# Set ListAdapter values to String

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

I have the following function which creates a ListAdapter;

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        AllProductsActivity.this, productsList,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID, TAG_NAME, TAG_PHONE, TAG_ADDRESS, TAG_SIZE,  TAG_CHES, TAG_PE, TAG_PRICE},
                        new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name, R.id.phone, R.id.address, R.id.Small, R.id.XC, R.id.Pep, R.id.price});
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Once the listview is updated, I want to get the 1st listview row which will have the highest `pid` value, and assign its values to some String values. To give you an idea of what I want, pseudo code as follows;

```
  String nam = highest pid.name;
  String pho = highest pid.phone;
  ...
```

Any thoughts on how to achieve that?

Comment: What do you wanna achieve? Kindly elaborate more.

Comment: He wants to get the name and phone etc. values of the listview row which has the highest 'TAG_PID' value, as I assume it's an int

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to **get back the adapter** from the listView and **check all the items** in that adapter to find out which has the highest pid.

It will be look like this:

```
    SimpleAdapter mAdapter = (SimpleAdapter)listView.getAdapter();
    Map<String, String> maxIdMap = null;
    for(int i=0; i<mAdapter.getCount(); i++){
        Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>)mAdapter.getItem(i);
        Integer pid = Integer.parseInt(map.get(TAG_PID));
        if(maxIdMap==null){
            maxIdMap = map;
        } else if(pid>Integer.parseInt(maxIdMap.get(TAG_PID))){
            maxIdMap = map;
        }
    }
    if(maxIdMap!=null) {
        // There is at least one record
        String name = maxIdMap.get(TAG_NAME);
        String phone = maxIdMap.get(TAG_PHONE);
        Log.d("Test", "Name: " + name + " Phone: " + phone);
    }
```